# OpenGL Setting SSBO for Compute Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, opengl-4

I've been having trouble sending data to an SSBO for use by a compute shader. Unfortunately, the [khronos docs say "TODO"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) and I cant make their sample code work, and people seem to do very slightly different things [Example 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/dy8fc0/compute_shader_and_ssbo_with_lwjgl/) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094598/opengl-compute-shader-ssbo/32094682) [Example 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/8viq4d/error_reading_back_from_ssbo_after_writing_with/) - can anyone help?

(I've snipped out other parts of code I've written that I don't think are relevant - [but the entire codebase is here](https://github.com/Turtwiggy/FightingGame/blob/d9ad07f6e1eaf93b5d38fa88278529430301db28/src/graphics/renderer.cpp) . Here's what I've got so far:

SSBO Initialization with some data

```
std::vector<glm::vec4> data = { glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) };

GLuint SSBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &SSBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SSBO);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), &data[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//the khronos docs put this line in
//glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, SSBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

Update loop

```
s_Data.compute_shader.use();

-- snip: bind a texture --

int ssbo_binding = 1;
int block_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(s_Data.compute_shader.ID, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "bufferData");
glShaderStorageBlockBinding(s_Data.compute_shader.ID, block_index, ssbo_binding );
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo_binding, SSBO);

glDispatchCompute( X workers, Y workers, 1);

//Synchronize all writes to the framebuffer image
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);

// Reset bindings
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo_binding, 0);
glBindImageTexture(0, 0, 0, false, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
glUseProgram(0);

-- snip: render output texture to screen --
```

Compute Shader

```
#version 430 core

layout(binding = 0, rgba16f) uniform image2D outTexture;

layout(std430, binding = 1 ) readonly buffer bufferData
{
    vec4 data[];
};

layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 8) in;
void main(void) {
    ivec2 px = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    ivec2 size = imageSize(outTexture);

    vec3 color;
    if(data.length() > 0)
    {
        //green = data
        color = vec3(0.2, 0.6, 0.2);
    } else
    {
        //red = bad
        color = vec3(0.6, 0.2, 0.2);
    }

    imageStore(outTexture, px, vec4(color, 1.0));
}
```

Currently my screen displays red indicating no data is being sent via the SSBO.

**Edit:**

Found the issue. The .length() method in the compute shader does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue in the compute shader.

The .length() was returning the wrong value. I queried data[0] and data[1] and they returned the correctly set values in the compute shader - so this was the problem (but I don't necessarily have the solution)